# Common Lisp on Heroku with Hunchentoot?

Tags: heroku, common-lisp, hunchentoot

Has anyone been able to successfully deploy an app on Heroku with the [Heroku Common Lisp Buildpack](https://github.com/mtravers/heroku-buildpack-cl) using Hunchentoot?

I'm getting a

```
!     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected
```

and I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, or if it isn't supported yet

**UPDATE:**

The above error was due to a missing heroku-setup.lisp file. Heroku now accepts the push, but trying to access the website gives an error.

Mike Travers answered the question: "[No, it's not currently supporting Hunchentoot, but it wouldn't be hard to add that.](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/comp.lang.lisp/TKM3eFyObLw)".

I guess the question now remains is who is capable to add that functionality?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

jsmpereira has added sbcl/hunchentoot capabilities.  https://github.com/jsmpereira/heroku-cl-example

Answer (score 3):

See also https://github.com/bhyde/heroku-buildpack-ccl64-example1 which is an example of doing that via a buildapp that provides ccl64 + quicklisp + asdf